# How to prove the integrality of this Eisenstein Series?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, complex-multiplication

Cohen and Strömberg included in their book [Modular Forms: A Classical Approach](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-179/) the chapter "A Brief Introduction to Complex Multiplication" (pp. 199-203).

In this chapter (p. 202) we find Proposition 5.10.6, which can be rephrased as follows:

> If $\tau$ is a CM point and $\Omega=\eta(\tau)^2$ with the Dedekind $\eta$-function, then $\sqrt{D}E_2^*(\tau)/\Omega^2$ is an algebraic integer, where $D$ is the discriminant of $\tau$.

Unfortunately, the proof begins with "we only prove algebraicity, not the integrality".

**Question: How exactly can I prove the integrality? I'm looking for a proof which is at least as detailed as Cohen/Strömberg's book; or a reference for such a proof.**

Edit: Here is a direct link to the relevant pages (thanks to reuns): [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8R0vDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA202#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Edit 2: The coefficients of the [Chudnovsky-Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm) can be computed as the value of
$$s_2(\tau):=\frac{E_4(\tau)}{E_6(\tau)}\cdot E_2^*(\tau)$$
at $\tau=\frac{1+i\sqrt{163}}{2}$, where we have
$$\frac{1-s_2(\tau)}{6} = \frac{13591409}{545140134}.$$
It is easy to compute the *approximate* value of this, but for proving that this value is *exact*, I still need to prove integrality. For the precise context, see [Prop. 10.2 (page 39)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00533), which is used in the end of the proof of 10.3 (page 40).

Also, Berndt and Chan write [here on p. 78](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1258138255):

> These authors [the Chudnovskys and Borweins] have calculated these coefficients, but we are uncertain if these calculations are theoretically grounded.

Unfortunately, they continue calculating the coefficients using minpoly() in MAPLE. I would like to give a complete proof of the Chudnovsky-Formula, only this bit remains open...

Comment: You need to make clear the relations you know on $j,E_4,E_2,E_2^*,\Delta,\eta$, the key is that $j(\tau)$ is an algebraic integer, whose proof is in every text on elliptic curves with CM

Comment: ok. Which relations do I need for the proof? Especially for $E_2$ and $E_2^*$ I don't know any relations besides $E_2^*=E_2-\frac{3}{\pi Im(\tau)}$

Comment: See OP's other questions where most of the clues are given. Some of those things are weight $0$ modular, a polynomial of those are modular for the full modular group so in $\mathbb{Q}(j)$, and it suffices to check the polynomial is monic with integer coefficients to extend the integrality of $j(\tau)$ to $f(\tau)$ and $f(\tau)g(\tau)$ https://mathoverflow.net/q/311879/84768